# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module bin/hello.ko: Invalid module format

Tags: linux, driver, kernel-module

I have kernel version 5.4.0-132-generic (from uname output). And I've installed 4.15.0-23-generic headers.

I compiled my kernel module for 4.15.0-23-generic.

I am trying to insert the module after compiling and getting the above error.

Can you please help me insert the module without errors? Where should I change?

Comment: You can only insert modules that were built for the running kernel. So you need to install 5.4.132-generic headers and build the kernel module for 5.4.132-generic. (But I think there is a typo in your question and you actually have 5.4.0-132-generic.)

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Okay from your comment I get that I need to downgrade the kernel to 4.15.0-23-generic. My kernel module is getting inserted in 5.4.0-132-generic. Do you know any safe method where I can install 4.15.0-23-generic kernel alongside my existing 5.4.0-132-generic kernel?

Comment: Can't you just build the module for the kernel you are currently using? Why do you want to downgrade the kernel (if that is even possible for your Ubuntu version)?